# Is it possible to pack the property view columns?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

We have an existing RCP app which uses the property view from `org.eclipse.ui.views` (version 3.6.0-SDK-3.7.2). I am wondering if there is a way to pack the columns of the `PropertySheetViewer`?

I am new to the RCP world and am not clear about how our app leverages this class. All I can see is an implementation of `IPropertySourceProvider` which seems to be used for populating the property view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't pack the columns.

`PropertySheetViewer` uses a control resize listener and adjusts the first column to 40% of the width and the second column to the rest of the width.

Comment: So if property name is longer than the default width the only way end users can increase it is by manually dragging to increase the column width? Are there any other workarounds available?

Comment: I don't know of anything. The Properties view is fairly minimal.